# Content Management systems CMS java based tool?

Tags: java, sharepoint, content-management-system

Please i need to know if there are any CMS or any corresponding for Microsoft sharepoint but in JAVA language.
Thanks

Comment: How about googling or binging it?

Answer (score 5):

- Nuxeo ECM  : http://www.nuxeo.com
- Alfresco : http://www.alfresco.org
- http://www.flexive.org/products/cms.html
- Jahia http://www.jahia.com/cms/home.html

**Magnolia**

Magnolia is the first open-source JSR-170 compatible Content-Management-System (CMS). Its main goal is ease of use for all parties involved in running a CMS. It features a very flexible structure, platform-independence through the use of Java and XML, a simple to use API, easy templating through the use of JSP, JSTL and a custom tag library, automatic administrative UI generation, transparent and uniform data access to multiple data repositories through JSR-170, easy configuration through XML, easy application integration and easy deployment as a Java EE servlet.

**CocoBlog**

CocoBlog is a free weblogging software tool based on Apache Cocoon and Apache Xindice . At the moment it is able to manage a single-user weblog , stored in an XML repository and publish it via Cocoon. The use of Cocoon allows to obtain a nice separation of content and presentation, so that the appearance of the pages is entirely determined by XSLT stylesheets.

**Roller Webllogger**

Roller is server-based weblogging software, a web application that is designed to support multiple simultaneous weblog users and visitors. Roller supports all of the latest-and-greatest weblogging features such as comments, WYSIWYG HTML editing, page templates, RSS syndication, trackback, blogroll management, and provides an XML-RPC interface for blogging clients such as w:bloggar and nntp//rss.

**MiniBlog**

Small tool to manage Blog.

**SimpleWeb**

A wiki Plug-n-play set up using integrated internal Java database (hSQLDB) - or MySQL db. HTML-subset editing. No weird Wiki-syntax to learn. Page previews and full archives of all changes made. Integrated basic searching. Automated sign-up of users with email confirmation and forgotten password notification. File Uploads to be used on the page (for images mostly) Weblogs.com pings when users make an update RSS file of latest updates for news aggregators and email to admin notification. Userland Radio OPML document conversion (browse the wiki using your Instant Outliner).

**XML2blog**

XML2blog is a small Java package designed to simplify the process of converting XML documents to Blogger templates, getting around the problems with Blogger's

**Cocoon Apache**

Apache Cocoon is an XML publishing framework that raises the usage of XML and XSLT technologies for server applications to a new level. Designed for performance and scalability around pipelined SAX processing, Cocoon offers a flexible environment based on the separation of concerns between content, logic and style.

**Cofax**

Cofax is a powerful web based Content Management System used to edit and manage the Online Editions of 16+ Newspapers. It was developed as Open Source software. Majority of the code was written by Knight Ridder employees, with additional code contributed by others under an Open Source license.

**OpenCms**

OpenCms is a Java based website content management system. It ist developed by the OpenCms group and uses the LGPL Open Source license.

Also you can find following links helpful:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems
- http://java-source.net/open-source/content-managment-systems
- http://www.opensourcecms.com/
- http://www.scriptol.com/cms/list.php